# Change view like page turn iphone/ipad cocoa

Tags: cocoa, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to change the view from right to left like a page turn whatever be the iphone orientation (landscape or portrait)..
curlup/down is just similar, but not work in landscape mode

A page touch API is awesome, but its paid.
http://www.code-flakes.com/2009/12/papertouch-api.html

is any body help me something similar to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) project might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using cocos2d. There you can use:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1 scene: newScene backwards:NO]];
```